# Cross Compiling For Arch Arm Does Not Produce A Functional Executable

Tags: c, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, archlinux, archlinux-arm

I installed [Arch Arm](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2) onto an Rpi3, then rsync'd sysroot to an x86_64 Arch Linux installed on a Lenovo thinkpad.

I then installed the [arm-linux-gnueabihf](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-i686_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz) Linaro cross compiler

To avoid any problems I used absolute paths in compilation:

```
/home/sameh/Rpi/Compiler/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc\
 --sysroot=/home/sameh/Rpi/Arch/ArmV7/root\
 -o stress stress.c -lm
```

The code compiles fine, however when I execute it on the Rpi3 it has no output.

It doesn't freez the Pi, I can `ps aux` and see the child processes created by `fork()`.

But none of the debug statements are printed and none of the processes exit.

**Edit**

This code is based on the [stress](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/) library.  For an MCVE I minimized it to only the `hogcpu` function

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int hogcpu (void);

int
hogcpu (void)
{
  for(int i=0; i < 1000000; i++)
    sqrt (rand ());
  return 0;
}

int main()
{

  struct timespec start, end;
  double cpu_time_used;
  int pid, children = 0, retval = 0;
  long forks;
  int do_dryrun = 0;
  long long do_backoff = 3000;

  long long do_cpu = 1;
  long long backoff, timeout = 0;

  /* Calculate the backoff value so we get good fork throughput.  */
  backoff = do_backoff * forks;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start); 

  while ((forks = (do_cpu + do_io + do_vm + do_hdd)))
  {
    if (do_cpu)
    {
      switch (pid = fork ())
        {
        case 0:            /* child */
          alarm (timeout);
          usleep (backoff);
          exit (hogcpu ());
        case -1:           /* error */
          break;
        default:
          ++children;
        }
      --do_cpu;
    }

  }
  /* Wait for our children to exit.  */
  while (children)
  {
    int status, ret;

    if ((pid = wait (&status)) > 0)
    {
      --children;
      if (WIFEXITED (status))
      {
        if ((ret = WEXITSTATUS (status)) == 0)
        {
          printf( "<-- worker %i returned normally\n", pid);
        }
        else
        {
          printf( "<-- worker %i returned error %i\n", pid, ret);
          ++retval;
          printf( "now reaping child worker processes\n");
          if (signal (SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
            printf( "handler error: %s\n", strerror (errno));
          if (kill (-1 * getpid (), SIGUSR1) == -1)
            printf( "kill error: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end); 
  cpu_time_used = (end.tv_nsec = start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
  /* Print final status message.  */
  if (retval)
  {
    printf( "failed run completed in %.2f s\n", cpu_time_used);
  }
  else
  {
    printf( "successful run completed in -- %.2f s\n", cpu_time_used);
  }

  exit (retval);
}
```

I can successfully compile and execute it on the the Pi with:

```
[alarm@control ~]$ gcc stress.c -o stress -lm
[alarm@control ~]$ ./stress 
<-- worker 16834 returned normally
<-- worker 16835 returned normally
<-- worker 16836 returned normally
successful run completed in -- 0.90 s
```

However, when cross compiled and transferred to the Pi, the behavior described above is what I am seeing.

***Note***

This may well have to do with the `clock_gettime` call.  When I replace this with a `clock()` function call, I can compile and run it on the laptop, but compiling on the Pi with `gcc` has the same behavior above.

When using `clock_gettime` and compiling on the Pi, it works fine.

Comment: Can you get it down to an MCVE?

Comment: Sure, trying so now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was how the `long forks;` variable was initialized. I am not well versed in compilers, but because `forks` was not initialized, the calculation `backoff = do_backoff * forks;` resulted in a random negative number.

This blocked the call `usleep (backoff);` from finishing.  So initializing `forks` to 1 fixed the problem.

I would have thought that `forks` should have been initialized to `0` by the compiler as past of the `bss_data` so I am not sure why it didn't.  Probably need more research into that part, but the code executes fine now with cross compiling.

Comment: "I would have thought that `forks` should have been initialized to 0 by the compiler as past of the `bss_data` so I am not sure why it didn't" `forks` is a local variable, if you leave it uninitialized it will get whatever happens to be on the stack/register in its place; more in abstract, the C standard says that it's undefined behavior to read from an uninitialized variable. `.bss` is for globals (more precisely: for static storage duration variables, i.e. globals + `static` locals, which are globals in disguise), which are guaranteed to be 0 if not explicitly initialized.

Comment: By the way, this would have been spotted immediately when compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -O3`. You should get in the habit of always compiling with most warnings enabled to avoid these traps.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/8SpbWH for example. BTW in your original code `do_io`, `do_vm` and `do_hdd` are missing.